# stack level too deep in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

When I try to perform following code on specs it gives me `stack level too deep`. Works fine in the console.

```
def order_fulfillments_without_receipts
      @order_fulfillments_without_receipts = []
      OrderReconciliation.includes(:order_fulfillment).
        where(data_entry_status: OrderReconciliation.data_entry_statuses[:pending_entry]).
        find_in_batches do |group|
          group.select do |reconciliation|
            select_reconciliation?(reconciliation)
          end
        end
      @order_fulfillments_without_receipts
    end

    def select_reconciliation?(reconciliation)
      order_fulfillment = reconciliation.order_fulfillment
      receipt_urls_empty = order_fulfillment.get_receipt_urls.empty?
      order_fulfillment_id = order_fulfillment.id
      @order_fulfillments_without_receipts << order_fulfillment_id
      receipt_urls_empty || order_fulfillments_without_receipts.include?(order_fulfillment_id)
    end
  end
```

How should I fix it to avoid `stack level too deep`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in your code, last line of the `select_reconciliation?` method after the `||` you have `order_fulfillments_without_receipts` but I think you meant `@order_fulfillments_without_receipts`

Without the `@` you're calling the `order_fulfillments_without_receipts` method, hence the infinite loop.

Why this is happening in your tests and not in your console must be to do with what `receipt_urls_empty` is in each case, in your tests it's `false` and in your console it's `true`.